# Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.1 components are not rendering correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was just checking angular material 2 and none of the component is working correctly in my application.the version of angular material 2 is `2.0.0-beta.1`.

I just followed the [getting started guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md) provided on the angular material 2 github repository.

This is my html template,

```
<md-card>
  <button md-button>FLAT</button>
  <button md-raised-button md-tooltip="This is a tooltip!">RAISED</button>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary">PRIMARY RAISED</button>
  <button md-raised-button color="accent">ACCENT RAISED</button>
</md-card>

<md-card>
  <md-checkbox>Unchecked</md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox [checked]="true">Checked</md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox [indeterminate]="true">Indeterminate</md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox [disabled]="true">Disabled</md-checkbox>
</md-card>

<md-card>
  <md-radio-button name="symbol">Alpha</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button name="symbol">Beta</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button name="symbol" disabled>Gamma</md-radio-button>
</md-card>
```

which rendered like this in the browser.

[image: output screen shot]

I am clueless here. I need help to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always apply a theme to material:

You can include a theme file directly into your application from `@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt`

All you have to do is add an import into your style `css/scss`:

for example:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

You can also define a custom theme. For more information you should read the theming readme:

[**custom material theming**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md#defining-a-custom-theme)

Comment: Thanks a lot @PierreDuc. This is what i was missing. After applying the theme my application rendered correctly. thanks again.